# How do I work with the 'all' collections to use with the File System Route API in Gatsby.js?

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I'm looking to work with Gatsby.js' [File System Route API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/routing/file-system-route-api/) to generate pages from collections in a private GraphQL API. It seems like the File System Route API always uses an 'all' collection request to generate these (`allFile`, `allSite`, `allPost`, etc).

Because my data is coming from a separate API, there is no equivalent 'all' collection in Gatsby's schema, and my data is also namespaced inside a field by the `gatsby-source-graphql` plugin.

Is it possible to define my own 'all' collection for Gatsby to use? I would like to alias `allFacilities` to `my-remote-api { facilities }`, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

If not, is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File System Route API is the new brand was developed by Gatsby (`^2.26.0`) to create pages dynamically, removing the GraphQL query of the `gatsby-node.js` and using a syntax notation in the `/pages` folder (`{}`,`[]`,`()`, etc).

Following your use-case, you will need to infer and modify the schema by prefixing the "all" keyword (maybe using `createNodeFactory` and `createNodeHelpers` from [`gatsby-node-helpers package`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-node-helpers), without knowing exactly your data schema and structure it's difficult to guess a sample code), but the idea is:

```
  const nodeHelpers = createNodeHelpers({
    typePrefix: 'Shopify',
    createNodeId,
    createContentDigest,
  })
}
```

By default, this will prefix the "all" keyword, creating a `allShopify` node, queryable and usable by the File System Route API.

On the other hand, there's the "old" way: using GraphQL in your `gatsby-node.js`, using the `createPage` API to create pages dynamically, passing data (typically a unique identifier) using the context, and, in the template, using another query filtering by that unique value to get your data (i.e: in the `gatsby-node.js` file you query for all posts and create pages dynamically (using the `createPage` API) for each post, using the slug value. Then, you pass an identifier (the slug, or the title) using the context and, in your template (not `/pages` as File System Route API) creating a filtered query by this unique value to get your post data).

If you are not able to customize your node with the helpers, maybe the second approach fits your requirements. Here you have a [guide provided by Gatsby docs about that part](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/).